# No matching server found with minimum required memory for the node [AppServer] on DCHQ

Tags: mysql, memory, docker, websphere, yaml

I am trying to run an app on DCHQ platform, these are my VM configurations on azure cloud

CPU 2
Memory 3GB
Disk 162GB

This is the YAML

```html
AppServer:
  image: websphere-liberty:webProfile6
  publish_all: true
  mem_min: 20000m
  host: host1
  cluster_size: 1
  environment:
    - database_driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    - database_url=jdbc:mysql://{{MySQL|container_ip}}:3306/{{MySQL|MYSQL_DATABASE}}
    - database_username={{MySQL|MYSQL_USER}}
    - database_password={{MySQL|MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}}
    - LICENSE=accept
MySQL:
  image: mysql:latest
  host: host1
  mem_min: 9000m
  environment:
    - MYSQL_USER=root
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=names
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD={{alphanumeric|8}}
```

I see this error:

No matching server found with minimum required memory for the node [AppServer]

The memory is under 3gb, what could possibly I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo.  20000m is 20GB, not 2GB.

(Similar typo in other section)